# How to stop c++ from rounding to closest integer

Tags: c++, cmath

I'm doing an area of a cylinder calculator and for some reason, c++ is rounding to the nearest number , here's my code:

```
int volume()
{
    int radius;
    int height;
    double long volume;
    double pi;
    pi = 3.14;
    cout << "Enter Radius: ";
    cin >> radius;
    cout << "Enter height: ";
    cin >> height;
    volume = radius * radius * height * pi;
    return volume;
}
int main()
{
    cout << "Formula Calculator \n";
    cout << "The volume  is " << volume();
    return 0;
}
```

It always rounds the answer to the nearest integer pls help :(

Comment: Because you told it to return an `int`: `int volume()`

Comment: Your volume() function is returning an int. So you are requiring some rounding. Change the return type to double

Comment: [std::round](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) - See the "See also" section.

Comment: I changed it and it worked, thank y'all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double long volume()
{
    int radius;           //Radius of a cylinder
    int height;           //Height of a cylinder
    double long volume;   //The resulting volume of the cylinder
    double pi = 3.14;     //The constant pi

    cout << "Enter Radius: ";
    cin >> radius;        //User inputs radius of cylinder
    cout << "Enter height: ";
    cin >> height;        //User inputs height of cylinder
    volume = radius *  radius * height * pi ; // v = (pi)(h)(r)^2

    return volume;
}
int main ()
{
    cout << "Formula Calculator \n";
    cout << "The volume  is " << volume();

    return 0;
}
```

The only issue I found was with the declaration of your function. You used `int` instead of `double long` that you used to declare your resulting volume. Also remove the c from `cvolume()` in your main function.

Answer (score 0):

The function is returning an integer and it truncates the decimal.

```
double long volume()
{
  int radius;
  int height;
  double pi;
  pi = 3.14;
  cout << "Enter Radius: ";
  cin >> radius;
  cout<< "Enter height: ";
  cin >> height;

 return (radius *  radius * height * pi);
}
int main ()
{
  cout << "Formula Calculator \n";
  cout << "The volume  is " << volume();
  return 0;
    }
```